# Sign a multi-signature transaction with imported address

Tags: wallet, address, multi-signature, output-script-descriptors

I have an address with three compressed public keys:

```
SCRIPT="5221"$(cat compressed_public_key_1.txt)"21"$(cat compressed_public_key_2.txt)"21"$(cat compressed_public_key_3.txt)"53AE"
```

and I generated a P2SH address from here.

Now, I would like to use a descriptor to sign the multisignature transaction.

Previously, I used:

```
TX_SIGNED=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey $TX_DATA '["'$PK1'"]' '[{"txid":"'$TXID'","vout":'$VOUT',"scriptPubKey":"'$SCRIPTPUBKEY'","redeemScript":"'$REDEEM'"}]'  | jq -r '.hex')
TX_SIGNED=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey $TX_SIGNED '["'$PK2'"]' '[{"txid":"'$TXID'","vout":'$VOUT',"scriptPubKey":"'$SCRIPTPUBKEY'","redeemScript":"'$REDEEM'"}]'  | jq -r '.hex')
```

and it is still working. However, I want to know if I need to use `signrawtransactionwithwallet`.

To check this, I attempted:

```
PK1=`cat compressed_private_key_WIF_1.txt`
PK2=`cat compressed_private_key_WIF_2.txt`
PK3=`cat compressed_private_key_WIF_3.txt`


CHECKSUM=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "sh(multi(2,$PK1,$PK2,$PK3))" | jq -r .checksum)
bitcoin-cli importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "sh(multi(2,'$PK1','$PK2','$PK3'))#'$CHECKSUM'", "timestamp": "now", "internal": true }]'
```

I could import without any error. But when I try to use:

```
TX_SIGNED=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithwallet $TX_DATA '[{"txid":"'$TXID'","vout":'$VOUT',"scriptPubKey":"'$SCRIPTPUBKEY'","redeemScript":"'$REDEEM'"}]'  | jq -r '.hex')
```

I get this error:

"error": "Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)"

I'm using this kind of script for my study notes

Comment: Are the PK1 etc private keys or public keys? It won't work without private keys.

Comment: private keys, updated the question.

Comment: Does the address match exactly? You can use `deriveaddresses` on the descriptor.

Comment: thanks for the reply, no the address is different after using `deriveaddresses` but the Order of PB during creating the Redeem script is the same

Comment: Well if the address doesn't match, it's not a descriptor for the exact output you have, so it won't work. BTW: your  `SCRIPT` uses the same public key twice.

Comment: My fault, even with the fix, I don't have the same address. Maybe the problem could be the PB and PK order?

Comment: What is "PB"? Try `getaddressinfo` on the address that comes out of `deriveaddresses`; it may tell you what the exact redeemscript is.

Comment: You are correct, PB stands for the public key. It now works properly. With `deriveaddress`, I can observe the correct order of public keys. Perhaps the main issue was the script type with `compressed_public_key_2.txt` repeated twice. Unfortunately, for study purposes, I cannot attempt to send the transaction with just one signature, as I could with `signrawtransactionwithkey`. The error message provided valuable insights.